# How to use this Nuget package Bot.Builder.Community.Middleware.Typing?

Tags: c#, botframework

Hello i have a bot created in **Botframework V4** using **C#**.
I want my bot to have a typing indicator whenever LUIS or QnA Maker is taking time to respond.
How can i use [this nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bot.Builder.Community.Middleware.Typing/)?

Comment: Have you looked here? ... https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/samples

Comment: Actually, looking at it, I don't think that library even exists anymore.  If you look at the project site, there is no namespace for "Typing" anymore, they have other middleware projects but that one is non-existent.

Comment: Thank you for you input sir. i will still try to check the link later.

Comment: The Typing Middleware is available in the main BotBuilder-dotnet package: https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/4.3/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ShowTypingMiddleware.cs

Comment: Thank Sir @NicolasR!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to show an indicator before LUIS/QnA, include this before the calls to LUIS/QnA:

```cs
var typing = new Activity() { Type = ActivityTypes.Typing };
```

The typing middleware will show the typing indicator for every delayed message. If you want to implement the [Typing middleware](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/4.3/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ShowTypingMiddleware.cs) that @NicolasR mentioned, you don't have to do much.

In `Startup.cs`, add:

```cs
var typingMiddleware = new ShowTypingMiddleware(delay: 500, period: 2000);
options.Middleware.Add(typingMiddleware);
```

This should show a typing indicator for all messages that take longer than the specified `delay`. See [this line](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ShowTypingMiddleware.cs#L12) for more details.